# Synonymize various tags for reference requests

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, references

Something's been bothering me (and it may just be me) about one category of our tags.  When someone asks for references for a particular topic, their choices for tags seems to be:

`books` - with synonyms `textbooks`, `textbook`, `book`, `video`, `tutorial`

`references` - with no synonyms

`resources` - with no synonyms

I would think all of these would be "synonyms" of each other, and the "mother tag" (don't know if it has a term) should be the most general, say `references` or (as in the Math.SE) `reference-request`.  I have noted that the "general vs. specific" debate has been brought up here [before](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/5594), but I think generality makes more sense in this situation.

FYI, [This](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/5594) appears to be the post where `books` was chosen as the "mother" of the synonyms listed above.

Again, this just may be me who's bothered by this.

Comment: I think references and books are quite separate - books is a subcategory of references, but not synonymous. It appears that books is now a synonym for references on the main site, and that sits pretty oddly with questions like this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41726/pop-stats-books-are-there-any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following a [recent discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1700/930) initiated by Andre Silva, it has been proposed to backlist the [recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag.

Moreover, [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) has the following synonyms: [resources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), [book](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) (s), [tutorial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorial), [video](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video), [textbook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbook) (s).