# Delete ambiguous [recommendations] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion, references, blacklist-request

Under the tag [recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) there are 14 threads:

1. 10 threads deals with [recommender-system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommender-system) (49 uses). They are:
   [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60571/finding-similar-items-based-on-user-likes-and-dislikes), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56740/calculating-user-preferences-based-on-purchases-how-to-incorporate-different-va), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55797/svd-in-movie-recommendation), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/collaborative-filtering-through-matrix-factorization-with-logistic-loss-function), [5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41089/dataset-for-article-recommendation-with-demographic-data), [6](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37407/are-there-any-tagging-dataset-for-evaluating-a-recommender-system-e-g-user-ta) [closed], [7](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/inaccurate-r-prediction), [8](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18581/evaluation-methods-for-personalized-recommendation), [9](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/item-set-similarity-for-real-time-calculation-purposes), [10](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/nearest-neighbor-information-for-recommendation-engines).
2. 4 threads asks for [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) (237 uses). See bellow:
   [11](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/book-recommendation-for-mathematical-statistics) [duplicate], [12](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/the-biggest-difference-between-medical-statistics-and-biological-statistics), [13](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/how-to-learn-data-analysis) [closed], [14](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/counting-how-many-times-a-package-has-been-loaded-in-r) [closed].

**Solution chosen:**

There is another option of putting [recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) on the blacklist tag (like, not allowing it to be used).

**Actions:**

All threads were handled properly during multiple campaigns.

Comment: We also have [tag:best-practices] and [tag:rule-of-thumb] (and even [tag:expertise], which was used only once!). Since the purpose of this site is to provide guidance, expert opinion and thoughful recommendations, I don't see any interest in keeping the [tag:recommendations] tag alive.

Comment: +1. I don't think "recommendations" evokes the idea of "recommender-system" at all. The first is just an ordinary English word, while the second does now have a precise technical meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Based on my comment.]
We also have [best-practices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) and [rule-of-thumb](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-thumb) (and even [expertise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expertise), which was used only once!). Since the purpose of this site is to provide guidance, expert opinion and thoughful recommendations, I don't see any interest in keeping the [recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag alive.

As @Nick pointed out, there is no connexion between 'recommendations' and 'recommender system'. I would suggest killing the [recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag, and cleaning up the aforementioned threads.

**Edit (6 Sep.)**
I've removed the tag from the remaining threads. **It can safely be blacklisted now.**

Comment: Is it possible to [burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag) the tag, and then, blacklist it? This would decrease the necessity of retags, and would avoid it to be used again. If it helps, just let me know after some action is taken on the tag (remove,burninate,blacklist) and I volunteer to retag the above threads (maximum of 2 retags per day). Thanks once more.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, @Andre. We will take care of the [tag:recommendations] tag, and I appreciate your help in the retagging process.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I edited the question to clean it up and to emphasize the actions accomplished.