# Suggestion to make "sources" and "resources" synonyms of "references"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, references

While performing an action derived from another [CV meta question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1700/doubt-on-tag-recommendations) and re-looking this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/how-to-learn-data-analysis), I realized [sources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) (5 threads) and [resources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) (13 threads) have been used to mean [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) (245 threads). I saw "resources" was already [asked](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/tags-for-references) to be a synonym in 2011 (no answers, though), but "sources" was not mentioned there.

Comment: +1, these are good suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) and [resources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) have been make synonyms of [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references).

Comment: Thank you very much!