# Proposal: add reference-request as a synonym for references

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, references

[references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) has 718 questions, [synonyms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/references/synonyms) [books](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [sources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) and [resources](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and a [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/references/info) that seems to cover *requesting* references:

> "References" is our generic tag for questions seeking information
>   about books, papers, presentations, videos of lectures, on-line
>   tutorials, etc., regarding any subject matter that is on-topic for
>   Cross Validated.

[reference-request](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) currently has four questions ([one of them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143264/1352) I just retagged) and [no tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info).

I propose adding [reference-request](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) as a synonym to [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references). (I don't have five votes, so I'm posting here.) Thoughts?

The meta question [Tags for references](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1007/1352) is related.

Comment: Thanks for bringing our attention to that apparent duplicate! I agree with you and will be happy to merge these two tags, unless there are specific objections to that.

Comment: @chl: it doesn't seem to me like waiting any longer will generate any objections. Could you please merge the tags, and add [tag:status-completed] to this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two tags are now merged, and all threads tagged with [reference-request](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) have been updated.